# How to use std::for_each on a function pointer list

Tags: c++, boost

On the following code, how can i rewrite the for loop by using a std::for_each instruction.
I tried to use `boost::lambda::_1`, `boost::bind`, but I could not make it working.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() 
{ 
  std::vector<int(*)(const char*)> processors; 
  processors.push_back(std::atoi); 
  processors.push_back(reinterpret_cast<int(*)(const char*)>(std::strlen)); 

  const char data[] = "1.23"; 

  for(std::vector<int(*)(const char*)>::iterator it = processors.begin();
      it != processors.end(); ++it) 
    std::cout << (*it)(data) << std::endl;
}
```

Any hint to help me solve this problem are welcome.

EDIT: Solution

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>

int main() 
{ 
  std::vector<boost::function<int(const char*)> > processors; 
  processors.push_back(std::atoi); 
  processors.push_back(std::strlen); 

  const char data[] = "1.23"; 

  namespace bl = boost::lambda;
  std::for_each(processors.begin(), processors.end(),
      std::cout << bl::bind(bl::_1, data) << "\n");
}
```

Comment: Note that casting between function-pointer types and then dereferencing them is undefined.

Comment: What went wrong when you used std::for_each?  What did you pass to for_each as the third parameter... i.e. the thing to do for each element of the range?

Comment: Since you're already using Boost's functional implementation, you should be able to use `boost::function<int(const char*)>` instead of `int(*)(const char*)`.  It will handle the return-type conversion for `std::strlen` (from `size_t` to `int`).

Comment: @Brian: I actually did tried something like that `boost::bind(std::cout << boost::bind(_1, data) << "\n"` and `std::cout << (int(*)(const char*))boost::lambda::_1(data) << "\n"`

Comment: @James: you are right, I made the change.

Comment: Does your C++ compiler support lambda expressions?  `for_each(p.begin(), p.end(), [&](const std::function<int(const char*)>& f) { return f(data); })`

Comment: @james: both g++ and clang++ does not like it.

Comment: Clang does not yet support lambda expressions.  Recent versions of gcc do, though you'll need to use `-std=c++0x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `boost::lambda` and `'\n'` instead of `endl` are allowed, does the
following code meet the purpose?

```
namespace bl = boost::lambda;
std::for_each( processors.begin(), processors.end()
             , std::cout << bl::bind( bl::_1, data ) << '\n' );
```

Comment: Yes i did tried it before but there is a compile error: it looks like it is not capable to recognize the type of `bl::_1`.

Comment: Strange... For your information, the above code worked when I tested
on VC2005 and [ideone(gcc4.3.4)](http://ideone.com/L1KUO).

Comment: You are right!, I misunderstood: boost::bind and boost::lambda::bind. It is working perfectly. Now i understand why all my previous attempt did fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
void blah(int (*func)(const char *), const char *data)
{
    std::cout << func(data) << std::endl;
};

...

std::for_each(processors.begin(), processors.end(), boost::bind(blah, _1, data));
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, But i would like to avoid creating another class for this purpose.

Comment: I see..., Is it poosible to reproduce blah function using a boost::bind function ? I know it wont be really pretty. but it is for improving my understanding of boost::bind.

Comment: I found my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838679/how-to-use-stdfor-each-on-a-function-pointer-list/5839607#5839607

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to use [BOOST_FOREACH](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/foreach.html):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::function<int(const char*)> ProcessorFunc;
    std::vector<ProcessorFunc> processors;
    processors.push_back(std::atoi);
    processors.push_back(std::strlen);

    const char data[] = "1.23";

    BOOST_FOREACH(ProcessorFunc& proc, processors)
    {
        std::cout << proc(data) << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Or you could use a [ranged-based for loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Range-based_for-loop) from C++0x.